# looping through json in C# using JSONConvert not working as expected

Tags: c#, json

I need to parse this JSON and get the seatjson part and pass it to another function.

I dont know whether its due to the structure of JSON I;m not getting seatjson as a whole to pass it to another function.Im getting each attribute in seatjson.

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(savedseat.ToString());
        foreach (var item in dynJson)
        {

            var s = item.seatjson;
             BookSeats(s, PNR);
        }
```

My JSON below:

```
  [  
      {  
      "flightNumber":"0345",
      "seatjson":{  
         "totalBasePrice":null,
         "totalPrice":null,
         "totalTax":null,
         "currency":null,
         "validatingCarrier":null,
         "lastTicketingDate":null,
         "fareOptions":null,
         "recordLocator":null
      }
   },
   {  
      "flightNumber":"0464",
      "seatjson":{  
         "totalBasePrice":null,
         "totalPrice":null,
         "totalTax":null,
         "currency":null,
         "validatingCarrier":null,
         "lastTicketingDate":null,
         "fareOptions":null, 
         "recordLocator":null
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: well, its valid JSON, what happens in `BookSeats` and what is `PNR`

Comment: We pass the json string to an http web request in BookSeats..PNR is just a unique number to identify your flight booking..

Answer (score 1):

Use a type model. If in doubt, get the IDE to create it for you ("Edit", "Paste Special", "Paste JSON As Classes"), but something like:

```
    var flights = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Flight[]>(json);
```

What you do with each `Flight` in the array is up to you, of course!

DTOs, based on guesswork:

```
public class Flight
{
    public string flightNumber { get; set; }
    public Seat seatjson { get; set; }
}

public class Seat
{
    public decimal? totalBasePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? totalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? totalTax { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string validatingCarrier { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lastTicketingDate { get; set; }
    public string fareOptions { get; set; }
    public string recordLocator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your DTOs are obviously more likely to be correct, I just used http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @Jodrell I tweaked them by hand based on guesswork from the names, but : this "paste JSON as classes" is built into Visual Studio

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there a way to get the whole JSON String of seatjson{  
         "totalBasePrice":null,
         "totalPrice":null,
         "totalTax":null,
         "currency":null,
         "validatingCarrier":null,
         "lastTicketingDate":null,
         "fareOptions":null, 
         "recordLocator":null
      }

Comment: It is the JSON string which I need to pass to the function Book Seats

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar not really... most APIs expect you to either work with an entire string, or to deserialize an entire model. If you want the JSON of *part* of the model, you'll probably need to re-serialize the `Seat` data. The point is: when you deserialize, `seatjson` **isn't a string** - it is an object, and most serializers will want to treat it as such

Comment: Ok I have found a solution to my problem..It was too simple.. dynamic dynJson=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(savedseat.ToString());
                    foreach (var item in dynJson){
                      var flightnumber = item.flightNumber;
                        var seatJson = item.seatjson;} I only need to pass item.seatjson

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
public class Seatjson
{
    public object totalBasePrice { get; set; }
    public object totalPrice { get; set; }
    public object totalTax { get; set; }
    public object currency { get; set; }
    public object validatingCarrier { get; set; }
    public object lastTicketingDate { get; set; }
    public object fareOptions { get; set; }
    public object recordLocator { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string flightNumber { get; set; }
    public Seatjson seatjson { get; set; }
}
```

the you can do

```
var savedSeats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(savedseat.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my project to read data from same kind of json you have

```
public class Flight
{
    public string  flightNumber { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> seatjson { get; set; }
}

public List<Flight> GetJsonFileContentInList(string jsonFilePath)
{
    Stream jsonStream = MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytetes(jsonFilePath));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonStream);
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Flight>>(json);
}
```